# I cannot login and am getting this error message. .

Tags: login

Warning: ucwords() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/content/90/8526290/html/KATHLEENKLEAN/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/autoloader.php on line 151

I have rest my cookies and my cache. Please help, I've run out of options.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter of ucwords() is supported since PHP 5.5.16. Check your version of PHP, and see if you can upgrade it.

Comment: samdpedraza, I can't get to cpanel through go daddy and I can't update my php on GoDaddy. Any backdoors to get in through the WP login? I'm block from that point.